# Code coverage with behat

Tags: php, code-coverage, behat, test-coverage

We want to use the most current PHP_CodeCoverage API (https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage) in our project.

To be sure it's really the case we just made an addtional script in *bin/behat-coverage*

```
#!/usr/bin/env php    
<?php

require_once (\dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php');

// Making coverage according to https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage
$filter = new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Filter();
$filter->addDirectoryToWhitelist(\dirname(__FILE__).'/../src');
$filter->removeDirectoryFromWhitelist(\dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor');
$coverage = new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage(new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Driver\Xdebug(), $filter);

/**
 * Creates the code coverage.
 * NOTE! Behat calls the function exit (indirectly). So we have to make the coverage report in a function which
 * is fired on exit.
 */
function ____on_behat_shutdown____() {
    global $coverage;
    $coverage->stop();
    $writer = new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\Html\Facade;
    $writer->process($coverage, \dirname(__FILE__).'/../var/code-coverage-report');
}

register_shutdown_function('____on_behat_shutdown____');

$coverage->start('myproj');

require_once(\dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat');
```

This seems to work fine.
But:

Is there a way to make execution speed the same as issuing *vendor/bin/behat* directly?

Is this the best way to use the most current PHP_CodeCoverage API?

Is there a way to make the output colorful again in Git Bash/Power Shell?

Is there a way to custom adjust colors in the shells mentioned above?